# Formula to move certain characters from center of string to front of string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I have a date format that I need to standardize down a column of cells, like so:

Oct 4, 2013 4:29:35 PM

I need to have it so that it is this format:

04/10/2013

Or a least into a format that excel can read as a date such as:

4 Oct 2013

I have been able to create a formula to drop the time, but haven't been able to switch the day and month around:

=IF(ISNUMBER(E1),E1,LEFT(E1,LEN(E1)-11))

I am using excel 2010. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about formatting the date, instead? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8E10019E-D5D8-47A1-BA95-DB95123D273E

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately excel will not pick up this format as a date, and thus will not let me change it into another format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(E1,FIND(",",E1)-2,2)&" "&LEFT(E1,3)&MID(E1,FIND(",",E1)+1,5))
```

But this formula is very dependable on your culture. If your culture is NOT English, then it might be that `Oct` will not be recognised.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of cheating with VBA (I'm sure there's a formula that does this - just can't find it), but you could use something like:

```
Public Function ReturnDate(Target As Range) As Date

    ReturnDate = Int(CDate(Target))

End Function
```

Enter `=ReturnDate(E1)` and format the cell.